# Two level paging in operating system

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

In two level paging system

page table is divided into 512 pages each of size 2KB and PAS is divided into 512 frames with supported physical address of 21bit. Page table entries are 2B then size of logical address spacing is..?

PAS=(9+12)

inner page table having 512 pages so 9bits to represent also outer table 9bits

So LAS=9+9+12=30bits

Is it correct..?

Comment: This sounds like homework for an operating systems class, not a practical programming question.

Comment: I'm not able to solve this. How can i get help for this?

Comment: Read your textbook, use google, and ask for help from your TA.